# Querying database in Grails

Tags: database, grails

The values in database are saved as such
::{"rating1":"2","rating2":"4","rating3":"5","rating4":"0","rating5":"0"},
Now I need to acces the individual values like 2,4,5 etc.

I made a variable "rating" of the Domain Class type and tried accesing as object using (.) operator but it wont work and gives error:
:exception::groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: rating1 for class: java.lang.String

, I tried casting to array and list (as Array, as ArrayList, as List) etc but that wont work either.
Casting to List gives exception:exception::org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{"rating1":"2","rating2":"4","rating3":"5","rating4":"0","rating5":"0"}' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.List' .

Accessing like "rating[3]" gives answer "a". Should I use "rating[11]" to get value 2 or is there any way around.
What could be the possible solution. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You're storing a string, so you only have string operations available. You need to parse that string to get at the attributes individually (JsonSlurper perhaps?).

rating[character-position] is a bad idea IMO.

Maybe transients (check the GORM docs) would be useful.

```
class YourDomain {
    String yourField
    String getRating1() { new JsonSlurper().parseText(yourField).rating1 }
}
```

Maybe. Totally untested, just an idea.

Comment: Thankyou very much. I tried your idea and found a simpler way using JSON.parse(rating) and it works.